# Django Pagination

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-pagination

I need to make real pagination instead of paginating on all retreived data. The example in Django documentation site, is like;

```
def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        contacts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('list.html', {"contacts": contacts})
```

This code is paginating records on all retreived records. But there is a trouble. Trying to retreive all record takes many time if there are so many records. I need a solution to retrieve the records page by page from database.

Is there another solution to do this in Django?

Comment: This question has been answered before, see here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548744/django-lazy-queryset-and-pagination

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You make a false assumption. Django does not retrieve all objects when paginating: it slices the queryset appropriately, which uses LIMIT and COUNT on the SQL.

Comment: Do you mean; Contacts.objects.all() line in the code is given in question, does not retrieve all record?

Comment: Correct. Query sets are lazy, as the docs explain, and no db call is made until they are iterated or sliced.

Comment: Actually I should have mention that I'm using MongoDB and Mongo fork for DJango modelling. Probably this is for SQL databases, not Mongo fork. Because I tried it, It still retreives all data from db. It is probably lack of Mongo fork for DJango. But thank you I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

A `QuerySet` is a lazy object. When you assign `contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()`, Django will NOT hit the database. Until you call the methods such as `count()`, `filter()`, `first()`,..., or `contact_list[1:5]`, Django will really retrieve data from the database. SQL statements that Django generate will correlate to each method and these SQL statments will be sent to the DB.

E.g: `contact_list[1:5]` generate a SQL statement have `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses.

In `Paginator` class, the `QuerySet` will passed to the its constructor

```
paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25)
```

When you call `paginator.page(page)`, the statement is called:

```
return self._get_page(self.object_list[bottom:top], number, self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look inside Paginator class (django/core/paginator.py), it fetches only required pages. There is only one problem on big tables: if you want to show total page numbers you must make count(*) on entire table which can took a long time in some databases (i.e. postgresql, mysql with innodb).

BTW, try to use generic views in django, [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) would be fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Here we using `get_page()` to get page wise data(1 page contain 25 data).I would suggest for this like :

```
def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    contacts = paginator.get_page(page)

    return render_to_response('list.html', {"contacts": contacts})
```