# Restrict the initial queryset to objects in pagination in django-restframework

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am defining a `ModelViewSet` using `django-rest-framework`.
I need to override the default queryset to perform some processing on the queryset objects before rendering the response.

This process is time-expensive so I would like to execute it only on the objects that will be actually available to the consumer due to the paginated response, **instead** of applying this process to **ALL** the objects and applying pagination **AFTER** finishing my processing, which I can notice (correct me if I'm wrong) is the default behavior in DRF.

---

In short what I need is:

If the default queryset is `1000 objects`, but the pagination is restricted to `25 objects per page`, I want to apply my process only those `25 objects`. Please note there is no other constraints for reducing the final amount of objects other than pagination.

Is there a way to do this? 
Is overriding the default queryset a bad idea in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, @Gerard, I have added a (very) late answer to your question. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "easy" way to do that. In Django REST framework pagination is done in the same method as rendering.

So I guess the best way to go is to define your own Viewset and redeclare the list method:

```
from rest_framework.viewssets import ModelViewSet

class MyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):

  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object_list = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())                
    if not self.allow_empty and not self.object_list:                           
      warnings.warn(                                                          
        'The `allow_empty` parameter is due to be deprecated. '             
        'To use `allow_empty=False` style behavior, You should override '   
        '`get_queryset()` and explicitly raise a 404 on empty querysets.',  
        PendingDeprecationWarning
      )              
      class_name = self.__class__.__name__                                    
      error_msg = self.empty_error % {'class_name': class_name}
      raise Http404(error_msg)                                                

    page = self.paginate_queryset(self.object_list)                             


    ## INSERT YOUR CODE HERE


    if page is not None:
      serializer = self.get_pagination_serializer(page)                       
    else:       
      serializer = self.get_serializer(self.object_list, many=True)           

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Theory:**

As it has been stated before:

- [Django REST Framework Return Only Objects Needed For Pagination & Total Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36562507/django-rest-framework-return-only-objects-needed-for-pagination-total-count?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [Django lazy QuerySet and pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548744/django-lazy-queryset-and-pagination?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Django [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).
They only hit the database when they absolutely need to (*like when you are doing to do the processing before the query and pagination.*).

There are two parts on DRF's pagination process:

- The `paginate_queryset`
- The `get_paginated_response`

We can choose which part to override, depending on our needs (See the **Practice** part)

---

**Practice:**

Depending on what you really want to process, there are two options.

*For this I assume that we are going to extend/override the [`LimitOffsetPagination`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py#L319) class, which is easier for an example, but the same principles apply to every other DRF pagination.*

1. **Processing the model objects:**

   If you want the preprocessing to be executed on the model objects and be permanent on your database, you need to override the `paginate_queryset` method:

   ```
   class MyPaginationMethod(LimitOffsetPagination):

       def paginate_queryset(self, queryset, request, view=None):
           self.count = _get_count(queryset)
           self.limit = self.get_limit(request)
           if self.limit is None:
               return None

           self.offset = self.get_offset(request)
           self.request = request
           if self.count > self.limit and self.template is not None:
           self.display_page_controls = True

           if self.count == 0 or self.offset > self.count:
               return []

           """
           Do your processing here on the  
           queryset[self.offset:self.offset + self.limit]
           Which has actually self.limit (e.g 25) amount of objects.
           """

           return list(YOUR_PROCESSED_QUERYSET)
   ```
2. **Processing the paginated response:**

   If you want the preprocessing to be executed on the response and **NOT** to be permanent on your database, you need to override the `get_paginated_response` method:

   ```
   class MyPaginationMethod(LimitOffsetPagination):

       def get_paginated_response(self, data):
           """
           Do your processing here on the data variable.
           The data is a list of OrderedDicts containing every object's
           representation as a dict.
           """
           return Response(OrderedDict([
               ('count', self.count),
               ('next', self.get_next_link()),
               ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
               ('results', YOUR_PROCESSED_DATA)
           ]))
   ```