# Improving pagination and serialization time in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-rest-framework

I am using `ListAPIView` to render a list of objects. The response returns paginated results with `limit=50`. The queryset size varies from 0 to a few hundred thousands.

What I have noticed is that when the queryset size is small, the API response time is small. But as the queryset size increases, the API response time becomes very large.

Is pagination actually the culprit here? 
Is there a way to optimize the response time for `ListAPIView`s using pagination?

Comment: Are you applying any ``order``? If you are, you should consider indexing.

Comment: All the data is indexed. I am getting the results from Solr using django haystack.

Comment: Hey, @AnimeshSharma I have added a late answer to your question. Please, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the official django documentation, [querysets are lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy).

> QuerySets are lazy – the act of creating a QuerySet doesn’t involve any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won’t actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated.

Also, [pagination compliments queryset's laziness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548744/django-lazy-queryset-and-pagination?answertab=votes#tab-top).

**Therefore, the [culprit](https://pheeph.deviantart.com/art/The-Culprit-183071186) for your delay IS NOT pagination.**
Case closed...

---

But what is it then?

- [Processing the queryset before pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25732364/restrict-the-initial-queryset-to-objects-in-pagination-in-django-restframework/45637208#45637208). Hits the database multiple times, slowing the app down.
- `Ordering` as @sha256 suggests.
- Very costly queries perhaps (you can check that by [following the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/models/#faq-see-raw-sql-queries)).

What to do to get faster?

- [Data access optimization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/optimization/#database-access-optimization)
- [Solving performance problems in the Django ORM](https://medium.com/@hansonkd/performance-problems-in-the-django-orm-1f62b3d04785)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, the question is quite old. I was working with Solr and haystack at that time. The Solr query time was low but the overall API response time was high. 

I never got to the solution.