# How does django's pagination work in a django view

Tags: python, sql, django, pagination, lazy-evaluation

So I was reading about pagination, I have done it quite a few times writing this app but I was wondering how does pagination in django work at sql level.

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        contacts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        contacts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of     results.
        contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response('list.html', {"contacts": contacts})
```

Does `Contacts.objects.all()` get called evertime I am hitting the view ?
Or does `Paginator` maintains a state somehow ? What would the sql query look like for `paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25)` Are there generators being used behind the scenes and things are lazily evaluated?

Sorry if this is a dumb question, there is a lot of abstraction in Django and I seem to miss all the action behind.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The Paginator does not maintain state on the server between requests -- a new paginator is instantiated for every request. I think the duplicate question I have linked to answers the rest of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this duplicate link as answer, because title of your question is very readable and there is answer for all your question

[Django lazy QuerySet and pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548744/django-lazy-queryset-and-pagination)